# Multiple DynamoDB triggers for Lambda - Separate invocation per table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

If I have a Lambda function that has multiple DynamoDB Stream triggers, is it guaranteed that each Lambda invocation only contains records from one table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Each lambda invocation will get record from one table

Refer [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html)

Following is an extract from that web page

> The event your Lambda function receives is the table update information AWS Lambda reads from your stream. When you configure event source mapping, the batch size you specify is the maximum number of records that you want your Lambda function to receive per invocation.